# How to output a db timestamp as a date stamp in the client using the clients timezone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given a timestamp in the DB like so: 2012-06-06T00:27:33Z

What's the best way to render this in the browser for the user like so:

```
5/02/12 3:48 PM
```

Is it best to use a JS library to use the client to render in the client's localtime? What's the best practice here? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the `Moment JS` library for general date parsing and formatting. Its pretty sweet.

http://momentjs.com/

Your example would be basically:

```
var date = moment('2012-06-06T00:27:33Z');
console.log('Formatted is %s', date.format('M/DD/YY h:m A'));
>> Formatted is 6/05/12 5:27 PM
```

By default Moment parses in local time, doing the timezone conversion automatically.

Comment: Hey thanks that's cool, it's a little complex and big for our needs though. I also found this one, but it doesn't seem to work. Very small and solves the pain. http://code.google.com/p/jquery-localtime/wiki/Usage

Comment: so how could you apply this to all <time> tags or tags with a specific class?

Comment: Well, first you need to determine if you're going to do it purely client-side (using JS) or in fact do it server-side during rendering. Normally, if you have the users timezone on hand than doing it server-side is simpler (see the first answer). If you are going to do in in JS than it should be straight-forward to iterate over all `time` (or any other) elements, grabbing the value or attribute and instantiating some `Moment` classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails, in environment.rb add something like

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:browser] = "%d/%b/%Y %H:%m"
```

Take a look at this to format according to your tastes. http://www.onrails.org/2008/08/20/what-are-all-the-rails-date-formats

In the view you would put

```
<%= Model.date_field.to_s(:browser) %>
```

If you need to adjust for timezones, you will first need to query your user's timezone. There are several ways you could do this.

Then in the view you could use e.g

```
<%= Model.date_field.change(:offset => "+0300").to_s(:browser) %>
```

or

```
<%= Model.date_field.in_time_zone(-3).to_s(:browser) %>
```

or

```
<%= Model.date_field.utc.to_s(:browser) %>
```

or

```
<%= (Model.date_field.utc + Time.zone_offset('EST')).to_s(:browser) %>
```

There are any options!

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<%= article.created_at.local_time %>
```

you should use locales.

locales/de.yml

```
de:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%d.%m.%Y"
      short: "%e. %b"
      long: "%A, %d.%B %Y um %H:%M"
      only_day: "%e"
    day_names: [Sonntag, Montag, Dienstag, Mittwoch, Donnerstag, Freitag, Samstag]
    abbr_day_names: [So, Mo, Di, Mi, Do, Fr, Sa]
    month_names: [~, Januar, Februar, März, April, Mai, Juni, Juli, August, September, Oktober, November, Dezember]
    abbr_month_names: [~, Jan, Feb, Mär, Apr, Mai, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Okt, Nov, Dez]
    order: [ :day, :month, :year ]
  time:
    formats:
      default: "%A, %d.%B %Y um %H:%M"
      short: "%d.%m.%Y"
      long: "%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M:%S"
```

in views:

```
 <%= I18n.l current_article.created_at, :format => :long %>
```

and for the timezone conversion:

config/environments/development.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Berlin'
```